# Carrito de compras en Laravel 7 (actualizar producto)

Tags: php, laravel

estoy haciendo un carrito de compras y quiero modificar la cantidad de unidades de un articulo ya agregado al carrito pero no me funciona porque solo me agrega una sola cantidad de un articulo.

Este es el controlador para actualizar el articulo en el carrito:

```
public function update($id, $cantidad){
         $carrito = session()->get('carrito');
         $carrito[$producto->id]->cantidad=$cantidad;
         session()->put('carrito', $carrito);
         return redirect('carrito', compact('carrito', 'cantidad'));
       }
```

Esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('/carrito/{id}/{cantidad}','carritoController@update');
```

Esta es la vista del carrito:

```
@extends("layouts.header")
<h3>Carrito de compras</h3>
<br>
<div class="container">

  @if(session('carrito'))

  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th>Cantidad</th>
        <th>Subtotal</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($carrito as $producto)
      <tr>
        <td>
           {{$producto->nombre}}
        </td>
        <td>${{$producto->precio}}</td>
        <td>
          {{$producto->cantidad}}
        </td>
        <td>${{$producto->precio * $producto->cantidad}}</td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    @endforeach
  </table>
```

En el detalle del producto tengo un boton de compra con esta ruta que solo me agrega el producto al carrito pero solo agrega una sola unidad al mismo y no dos o tres:

```
<a href="/carrito/{{$producto->id}}/{{$producto->cantidad}}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Comprar</a>
```

Comment: Que error te da? O puedes especificar más la falla que tienes por favor!

Comment: @Mundoco   En la vista del detalle del producto tengo un boton "comprar" que me agrega el producto al carrito pero cuando quiero "comprar" mas de una vez el mismo producto, en el carrito solo agrega una  sola cantidad de dicho articulo. El boton de "comprar" tiene un boton con esta ruta: <a href="/carrito/{{$producto->id}}" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Comprar</a> que me almacena el producto pero nada mas

Comment: Válida con un condicional si la variable está definida y en caso afirmativo incrementa en 1 a la cantidad con un $cantidad +=1 y en caso igualala con la misma variable

Answer (score 0):

tengo algunas dudas de tu código, En tu función update recibes $id y $cantidad, pero nunca usas el $id y en $cantidad ¿que recibes?,  ¿la cantidad actual del producto en el carrito o la cantidad + 1 solo para actualizarla en el carrito?.
Quiero suponer que $id va a ser el índice de tu array carrito por ejemplo si el producto que compraste es el id 1, estas buscando $carrito[$id]->cantidad = $cantidad y luego asignas la cantidad que recibiste.
Lo que yo haría sería:

```
public function update($id){ // solo recibir el id del producto, a menos que si estes recibiendo la nueva cantidad
         $carrito = session()->get('carrito');
         // Buscar si el producto está en el carrito
         if (isset($carrito[$id]))
             $carrito[$id]->cantidad++; // Le aumentamos uno a la cantidad actual
         else
             $carrito[$id]->cantidad=1; // Aquí sería que insertaras el producto con la cantidad 1 ya que aun no existe en el carrito el producto
         session()->put('carrito', $carrito);
         return redirect('carrito', compact('carrito', 'cantidad'));
       }
```

Para ofrecerte bien la solución, publica la función donde creas el carrito.
Espero te sea de ayuda.